Sizing and positioning image and overlaying element within element css
I have a wrapper div and two elements within it. One is an image, and the other is an overlay. The image and overlay width needs to be 100% of the parent element (product-image-1) which is 250px in width. The overlay should appear above the image upon hovering. I have the code below, and there are a few issues. The first is the image width is set to 100% of the parent element, but it is much larger than the parent div. Secondly, the overlay is nowhere to be found. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I found similar questions but I haven't gotten anything to work. For .product-image I tried width and max-width.
HTML:
<div class="flex row">
    <div class="product-image-wrapper flex row" id="product-image-1">
         <img src="./images/product-img-1.jpeg" alt="" class="product-image">
          <div class="image-overlay"></div>
    </div>
</div>

CSS:
#product-image-1 {
    width: 250px;
}
.product-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.image-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    z-index: 2;
}
.image-overlay:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

Edit: Adding position: relative to #product-image-1 sizes the image properly, but the overlay isn't shown still.

Looks like you forgot to add position: relative to the wrapper.

Thank you, that sizes the image properly but the overlay isn't showing.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

The wrapper needed position: relative and .product-image position needed to be set to relative. That sizes the image properly and positions the overlay properly.
